# confusion of dont vs doesnt

Tags: word-choice, tenses, confusables

i have heard that it should does/does not for he/she/it and do/don't for i/you/we/they

But I am confused when i always get to hear people talking do and don't for he/she

Even in a lecture i listened now it was said as, "That lady don't" instead of "that lady does not"

Which one is correct?